# Is there a way to mask class values when being logged using Lombok logger?

Tags: java, spring, logging, lombok

I wanted to know if there's a generic way to mask specific class fields values when logged? i'm using Lombok logger.

for example:

```
@ToString(includeFieldNames = true)
public class Account{
    String name = "";
    String accountNumber = "";
    String code = "";
}
```

when logging the toString() i want to be able to mask the value but in a **generic** way (i know i can override the toString method but that will need to be done for each class specifically)

Answer (score 4):

Lombok now supports excluding fields from toString method using annotations

```
@ToString
public class Account {
    String name = "";
    @ToString.Exclude
    String accountNumber= "";
    String code = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, you can [exclude the field from the `toString` method](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString).

```
@ToString(exclude="accountNumber")
public class Account {
    String name = "";
    String accountNumber= "";
    String code = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dedicated class that holds objects that you need to obfuscate.

```
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class Account {
    String name = "";
    MaskedString accountNumber = "";
    String code = "";
}

@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class MaskedString {
    private String value; 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        new StringBuilder(value)
            .replace(0, 5, "XXXXX")
            .toString();
    }
}
```

This will replace the value of `accountNumber = "0123456789"` by `accountNumber = "XXXXX56789"`.

Comment: Thanks, i'm aware of this option but i dont want to remove it completely from the log, i just want to mask it.

Comment: @SamP. I'm not following. Can you provide an example of the desired output?

Comment: The string should appear with the accountNumber as masked (could be different way to mask it) for example: name=test, accountNumber=XXXXX6789, code=1234