# Replace logging of org.zalando.logbook.Logbook when web request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, slf4j

I have a Spring Rest Controller which can get this request:

```
logger_name: org.zalando.logbook.Logbook
message: {"origin":"remote","type":"request","correlation":"91ca9efbe5ed9f5d","protocol":"HTTP/1.1","remote":"172.30.10.1","method":"POST","body":{"bundleCode":"pro","clientInfo":{"clientId":"5-B4QTU240","phoneNumber":"+12223334455"},"interfaceInfo":{"appVersion":"string","appName":"string","platform":"invest"},"planId":1}}
```

I want to replace my +12223334455 number to +1******4455 in the log, and I've already made a method for it:

```
private static final String PHONE_MASK_PATTERN = "(?<=^.{2,%d}).";
public static String getPhoneRegexp(int phoneLength) {
        return String.format(PHONE_MASK_PATTERN, phoneLength - 5);
    }
```

But this request is looged not in handle, it's somewhere inside controller. What is the best way to mask my number using the method?

Comment: Here is a link that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194081/is-there-a-way-to-mask-class-values-when-being-logged-using-lombok-logger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define a `BodyFilter` bean with your replacement logic, something like this:

```
@Bean
public BodyFilter bodyFilter() {
    return merge(
            defaultValue(),
            replacePrimitiveJsonProperty(jsonProp -> jsonProp.equals("phoneNumber"), (jsonPropName, jsonPropValue) -> {
                String maskedValue = ... // mask jsonPropValue as you like
                return maskedValue;
            }));
}
```

Be sure to include the `org.zalando:logbook-spring-boot-starter` dependency in your project and have the `logbook.filter.enabled` property set to `true`

Reference:

https://github.com/zalando/logbook#spring-boot-starter

Comment: what is defaultValue() and where it shoul be taken from?

Comment: `org.zalando.logbook.BodyFilters#defaultValue`

Comment: ```(jsonPropName, jsonPropValue) -> {
                String maskedValue = ... // mask jsonPropValue as you like
                return maskedValue;```

Comment: the lambda doesn't work, it shows an error of jsonPropValue because it's not a String

Comment: What type is it then?

Comment: it is shown as a lambda param
the method ```replacePrimitiveJsonProperty``` asks for ```final Predicate<String> predicate, final String replacement```, it doesn't have the second predicate/lambda

Comment: I don't need a full replacement, I just need to replace some of the symbols

Comment: The code in the answer is tested with version `2.14.0` of `logbook-spring-boot-starter`. You might be using an older version where the method `public static BodyFilter replacePrimitiveJsonProperty( final Predicate<String> predicate, final BiFunction<String, String, String> replacement)` is not available. If that's the case I'd suggest updating to the latest version.

Comment: as I know, ```replacePrimitiveJsonProperty``` is a part of logbook-json, not ```logbook-spring-boot-starter```

Comment: Yes, logbook-spring-boot-starter 2.14.0 brings in logbook-json 2.14.0 if that helps.